# Killer Wireless-N 1102 bluetooth not working ubuntu

Tags: wireless

I've got this card Killer Wireless-N 1102, but the bluetooth doesn't work on 14.04 LTS. Initially I had 12.04, but it never worked.

I'd like to have it installed so did some research but didn't found how to solve the issue.

Any tips ?